# Pagination in WP Queries

Tags: php, posts, query

I've set up a filter on my blog posts, so that users can only display those which have a value matching an Advance Custom Field.

The query works - but only until you click to see the older posts. When it gets to page 2, all posts are displaying again. How do I get Wordpress to keep the query when navigating away from page 1?

Comment: Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425952/wp-pagination-loop-not-working-in-custom-theme/44428468#44428468) on other question for reference. I hope it will help you.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not working Jiten, I can't get out of the main wp-query loop! When stackexchange lets me post again I'll re-ask the question with my code.